# webapi action overload

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing

here are my actions

```
public AddressModel[] Get()
{
    return addresses.ToArray();
}

public AddressModel Get([FromUri]GetAddressModelById model)
{
    return Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id);
}
...
public class GetAddressModelById
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

the urls looks like this

```
domain:port/api/controller
domain:port/api/controller/[guid]
```

and the routing is the default routing.
When I run this i get the exception `Multiple actions were found that match the request`. what am I missing for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try domain:port/api/controller/model=[guid]

It would also be good if you could do:

public AddressModel Get([FromUri]Guid model)
{
 ...
}

Comment: I'll give the query string a try. I want to use a complex type rather than simple type to preform context specific validation within a controller action. this way the action is only concerned with the happy path.

Comment: using the model query string, but that doesn't work either. I may move my actions into separate controllers to avoid routing collisions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is because if you request for domain:port/api/controller, we cannot decide whether to dispatch it to `Get()` or `Get([FromUri]GetAddressModelById model)` with model set to null. You have following two options in this case

1. Use plain Guid type parameter instead of the class wrapper
2. Post your complex type in body instead of sending it through URI

Comment: that's what doesn't make sense though. why can't webapi distinguish between the uri's [GET]Address/ and [GET]Address/{guid}? My other option is to move the [GET]Address/ to another uri altogether. something like [GET]Addresses and [GET]Address/{guid}. I would rather keep them together, but it may be my only option.